# Pi equation with sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Recently in a class at school I was shown by my teacher that it is possible to show the value of pi using the formula

```
Pi = 2 * (2*2*4*4*6*6*8*8.....)/(1*3*3*5*5*7*7*9.......)
```

Where the integers used on the numerator and the denominater have to be equal. The more integers you use, the more accurate the number gets. I was wondering if there was a mathematical formula for the sequence of `2,2,4,4,6,6,8,8....` and `1,3,3,5,5,7,7,9,9......` so that I could write a basic program to calculate the value of pi to a certain accuracy. Are there any formulas which allow for this?

Comment: If the formula you wrote it correct, why not sinply consider the sequence $a_n=(2n)^2$ and $b_n=(2n+1)^2$? You can also use factorials

Comment: @b00nheT because the formula needs to have the same amount of integers on the top and bottom. Using your formulas you will always get on more value on the denominater than on the numerator

Comment: For what it's worth, this product converges to pi very slowly. If you really want to calculate pi to lots of decimals, there are much better ways. Have a look around the internet.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was surprised just how very badly/slowly it converges. 40000 terms is not enough for 6 significant digits.

Comment: @DRF: every increase of $n$ results in a factor $n^2/(n^2-1)$; in logarithms, this adds a term of order $1/n^2$. By integration, the tail of the series will decrease like $1/n$, i.e. very slooooowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you are using is $$A_n=2 \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i)^2}{(2n+1)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(2i+1)^2}=2(2n+1)\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i)^2}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2i+1)^2}$$ As said, this involves the gamma function and the result would approximate $\pi$ but very slowly.

Sooner or later, you will learn about series expansions and asymptotics. To give you an idea, for large values of $n$, you will have $$\frac{A_n}\pi=1-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{5}{32 n^2}-\frac{11}{128 n^3}+\frac{83}{2048
   n^4}-\frac{143}{8192 n^5}+\frac{625}{65536
   n^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)$$ Using this expansion for $n=10000$, it would give $$\frac{A_n}\pi=\frac{104854978723830989224941697}{104857600000000000000000000}\approx 0.999975$$ I meka a table of the decimal value of $A_n$ as a function of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & A_n \\
 1000 & 3.140807746 \\
 2000 & 3.141200077 \\
 3000 & 3.141330909 \\
 4000 & 3.141396335 \\
 5000 & 3.141435594 \\
 6000 & 3.141461768 \\
 7000 & 3.141480464 \\
 8000 & 3.141494486 \\
 9000 & 3.141505393 \\
 10000 & 3.141514119 \\
 11000 & 3.141521258 \\
 12000 & 3.141527207 \\
 13000 & 3.141532241 \\
 14000 & 3.141536556 \\
 15000 & 3.141540296 \\
 16000 & 3.141543568 \\
 17000 & 3.141546455 \\
 18000 & 3.141549022 \\
 19000 & 3.141551318 \\
 20000 & 3.141553385
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a couple of ways to get the two sequences you mention as a formula. Though I don't think any are "nice".

One possibility is $a_n=(\left\lfloor{n/2}\right\rfloor+1)*2$ and $b_n=(\left\lceil{n/2}\right\rceil+1)*2+1$ assuming you start at $0$.

Though I would say if you want to write a program this is a probably not the best way to go. A for loop would probably be much easier.

```
double pi_acc(int n){

int i=0;
double mypi=2,a=2,b=1;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){ 
   mypi*= (a/b);
   a+=( i & 0x01)*2;
   b+=( (i+1)&0x01)*2;
   }
return(mypi);
}
```

All together though the biggest issue is that this particular product converges to $\pi$ incredibly slowly. Roughly 40000 terms gets you 5 significant digits.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a shortcut way to compute factorials faster than by doing all products explicitly: the Stirling approximation formula. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates).

Very grossly speaking, it approximates $n!$ by $n^n$, which can be computed by logarithms, as $e^{n\log n}$. And $e$ can be raised to a larger power fast by iterative squarings ($2\log n$ multiplies instead of $n$).

Unfortunately, there is a "but": Stirling's formula requires... the knowledge of $\pi$.

Comment: Surely this formula would be to calculate all numbers not only the evens or only the odds

Comment: @R.Duggan: the adaptation to compute the double factorials is straightforward.